# rpy2 : DTW package not working with step pattern provided

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, rpy2

I am currently trying to use rpy2 to access "R" DTW (Dynamic time warping) package to calculate distance between multivariate time series. Maybe since the time series are really different that I am getting the error `"No warping path exists that is allowed by costraints"`

I think the default step pattern in the library is symmetric but i want to test it out with asymmetric step pattern , but the toy code is not working when i try to give step pattern as "asymmetric" . Following is the code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cluster
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robj


"""Example of DTW calculation, it's 2 variables , 5 timestamps and 16 timestamps each"""
R = rpy2.robjects.r
DTW = importr('dtw')

# Generate our data
template = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]).transpose()
rt,ct = template.shape
query = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]).transpose()
rq,cq = query.shape

templateR=R.matrix(template,nrow=rt,ncol=ct)
queryR=R.matrix(query,nrow=rq,ncol=cq)
alignment = R.dtw(templateR,queryR,keep=True, step_pattern=R.asymmetric)
alignment = R.dtw(templateR, queryR, keep=True)
dist = alignment.rx('distance')[0][0]

print dist
```

I have also looked into following example but it's not working:

[rpy2 dtw missing argument window.size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089501/rpy2-dtw-missing-argument-window-size)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The default step pattern in the library is symmetric2. To test with others type:

alignment = R.dtw(templateR,queryR,keep=True, step_pattern=DTW.asymmetric)

not R.asymmetric

Hope it helps